# Finding GCP project with Apps Script Client ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP project I want to bind to an Apps Script project. The problem is, there's already an Apps Script Oauth2 Client ID listed, and I have no idea what Apps Script project the GCP project is already bound to. All I have is the client ID, is there any way to find the apps script project with this? There's nothing in the logs for in in my Workspace environment. The client is also not any Apps Script project that I can see. I'd like to avoid creating a new project if possible.

Comment: The first part of the Client ID is the Google Cloud project number. Use this command to list the projects you have access to: `gcloud projects list`.

Comment: I have access to the GCP project it's in, I'm trying to find the apps script project

Comment: Did you login into the App Script Dashboard [link](https://script.google.com/)? That will show you the projects you have access to.

Comment: Yes, it's not on any project that I can see and I'm the only person who has access to the project (or uses apps script in general)

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible. The way to do this, if possible, is querying [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest) to get `GCP Project Number` of a `Script ID`.

Fortunately, it's already a known issue and the status is already **Assigned**.

See:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267670797 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/291716173